# How do I `.filter()` an array/object and return a new array with the original keys and not as an indexed array/object as filter return?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

```
var obj = {
    
    111: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    112: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    }, 
    113: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    ... 
}
```

I want to filter all `("isActive" === 0)` but keep the key set the same (which is equal to the user id) when returning the newObj:

```
newObj = {
    
    111: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    113: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    ... 
}
```

This is what I have now:

```
let newObj = Object.values(obj).filter( user => ( (obj.isActive === 0)));
```

which returns indexed keys

- no for loops (unless the ES6 `.forEach()` is a must).
- I would like an ES6 approach to this problem using filter/map/reduce if possible in this situation.
- loadash approach are ok, but I still want to see a "vanilla ES6" example before
- If I can get tip of how/where is best to learn and practice to filter arrays in all sorts of ways using these methods (loadash will be cool here too).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The truly FP way would be `reduce` with repeated object spread:

```
const filtered = Object.values(obj).reduce((p, e) => (!e.isActive ? {...p, [e.user_id]: e} : p), {});
```

```js
const obj = {
    111: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    112: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    }, 
    113: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    }
};
const filtered = Object.values(obj).reduce((p, e) => (!e.isActive ? {...p, [e.user_id]: e} : p), {});
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

That creates lots of unnecessary temporary objects, but adheres to FP principles (I think, I'm not "deep" on FP :-)) by not modifying objects in place.

Bending the rules a bit, we might modify a single object rather than creating lots of temporaries:

```
const filtered = Object.values(obj).reduce((newObj, e) => {
  if (!e.isActive) {
    newObj[e.user_id] = e;
  }
  return newObj;
}, {});
```

```js
const obj = {
    111: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    112: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    }, 
    113: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    }
};
const filtered = Object.values(obj).reduce((newObj, e) => {
  if (!e.isActive) {
    newObj[e.user_id] = e;
  }
  return newObj;
}, {});
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

(That can be written in fewer characters by abusing the comma operator, but it's less maintainable and harder to read.)

Without the FP restriction, I'd just use a loop:

```
const filtered = {};
for (const e of Object.values(obj)) {
  if (!e.isActive) {
    filtered[e.user_id] = e;
  }
}
```

```js
const obj = {
    111: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    112: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    }, 
    113: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    }
};
const filtered = {};
for (const e of Object.values(obj)) {
  if (!e.isActive) {
    filtered[e.user_id] = e;
  }
}
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: IMHO the loop version is much more readable, and probably by far the most performant, sometimes I wonder if FP requirements are not only just to look smart (when not simply false assumptions about simplicity and preformance, where in most case, FP falls behind regular loops)

Answer (score 2):

The "officially" suggested way to do object transformations like this is to "linearize" the object with [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), perform map/filter on key-value pairs, and put them back together with [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries). The latter is new, so you'd need a polyfill.

Example:

```js
// polyfill

Object.fromEntries = Object.fromEntries || function(pairs) {
    let obj = {};
    for (let [k, v] of pairs)
        obj[k] = v;
    return obj;
};


var myObj = {

    111: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    },
    112: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    },
    113: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    },
};

result = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(myObj)
        .filter(([k, v]) => v.isActive));

console.log(result)
```

Since you've asked for a FP solution, here's one possible generalization:

```
let apply = (x, fn) => fn(x);

let pipe = (...fns) => x => fns.reduce(apply, x);

let transform = fn => pipe(Object.entries, fn, Object.fromEntries);

let filter = fn => a => a.filter(fn);

let filterObject = fn => transform(filter(fn));

let removeInactive = filterObject(([k, v]) => v.isActive);

console.log(removeInactive(myObj))
```

FP is about expressing your program in terms of function composition, not about writing loops "inside out" with reduce.

Comment: I cannot be picky on an answer and not on another, I would loose my honour! I totally agree with your last comment, but isn't the use of `filter` a way to write a loop without admitting it?

Comment: @Kaddath: the point is, if you take a chunk of procedural code and wrap it in reduce, this doesn't make your program "functional".

Comment: Good point, I'll keep that in mind, totally adds to my holy fight against windmills of the many "useless" uses of FP. Not only does it affect performance and readablility, but in most examples I've seen, it was not even properly functional then!

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries, filter and build new objects.

```js
var object = { 111: { user_id: 111, user_name: "user111", isActive: 0 }, 112: { user_id: 112, user_name: "use112", isActive: 1 }, 113: { user_id: 113, user_name: "use113", isActive: 0 } },
    result = Object.assign(...Object
        .entries(object)
        .filter(({ 1: { isActive } }) => isActive === 0)
        .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Would this be a "better practice" than using .filter/.map/.reduce ?

Comment: @RickSanchez, in my eyes yes, but for others it might be different.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a generator function that takes an iterable:

```js
// make object type iterable

function* objEntries(o) {
  for (let k in o)
    yield [k, o[k]];
}

// generator function that takes an iterable

const itFilter = p => function* (ix) {
  for (const x of ix)
    if (p(x))
      yield x;
};

const obj = {
    111: {
        user_id: 111,
        user_name: "user111",
        isActive: 0
    }, 
    112: {
        user_id: 112,
        user_name: "use112",
        isActive: 1
    }, 
    113: {
        user_id: 113,
        user_name: "use113",
        isActive: 0
    }
};

// exhaust the iterator with a strict evaluated fold

const itFoldStrict = f => acc => ix => {
  let acc_ = acc;

  for (const x of ix)
    acc_ = f(acc_) (x);

  return acc_;
};

const ix = itFilter(([k, o]) => o.isActive === 0)
  (objEntries(obj));

// nothin has happened here due to lazy evaluation

// unleash the effect (of constructing the filtered object)

console.log(
  itFoldStrict(acc => ([k, v]) => (acc[k] = v, acc))
    ({}) (ix));
```

This way the algorithm

- is lazy
- doesn't produce intermediate values

Comment: Good idea, unfortunately the OP wants an object back, not an array.

Comment: I am being picky here on purpose, but I would tend to consider that `objValues` and `itFilter` are indeed intermediate values. Interesting solution though

Comment: @georg I didn't want to make all the work for the OP. Anyway, since you insisted...

Comment: @Kaddath Yes, these generator functions produce intermediate values, but merely tiny iterator objects one at a time. The algorithm doesn't build up an entire `Array` structure.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine too:

```
var newObj = Object.entries(obj).filter(value => {return value[1].isActive ===0});
```